# Can asp.net web application communicate with standalone visual c++ application?

Tags: asp.net

Can I integrate a asp.net website with Visual c++ standalone application? 
The request should go from asp.net website to visual c++ application and the result should be used by asp.net website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question actually includes part of the answer. The two processes, **regardless of the language they are written in**, they would have to communicate exchanging data in a client-server fashion. Therefore, the C++ process would have to act as a server and ASP.NET as a client requesting data from the server.

Therefore, you could **build a [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)**, either [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) or [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) using C++ and reference this web service through your ASP.NET process asking for data from the C++ server. [Here you could find a tutorial on how to build a web service using C++](http://www.atomki.hu/atomki/CompGroup/2share/guide-to-creating-cpp-web-services.pdf). [Here you could find a .NET tutorial on web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Another, **simpler but less structured** approach would be to use something like a vault, perhaps a file or a database. The results would be written in the vault anyway (even if they were not asked and the ASP.NET process would retrieve them whenever it wants.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 2):

You can execute a process in the filesystem, independently of the language it was written on.
Like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C++App.exe", "command line arguments like /page getdata.aspx ... ");
processInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

Process proc = Process.Start(processInfo);

proc.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, errorLine) => { if (errorLine.Data != null) Trace.WriteLine(errorLine.Data); };
proc.OutputDataReceived += (sender, outputLine) => { if (outputLine.Data != null) Trace.WriteLine(outputLine.Data); };
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

proc.WaitForExit();
```

Regards.